# PyInstaller doesn't read libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyinstaller, importerror

I finished making Snake in Pygame and I wanted to convert it into an app in pyinstaller. I'm working on a Mac. Even though I clearly installed the pygame module, and I even to installed it on the files path, when I run the .exe app after I converted it, it still gives me the `ImportError: no module named pygame`.
You can obviously tell, I DO have pygame because I made my program in it. Happily, when I run the code from an editor, the program works fine. Can you please help?

Comment: Something like that would also depend on external DLL files. You may have to add additional configuration to the Pyinstaller spec file. I can't tell you exactly what that would be, sorry.

Comment: Can you run your program from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used a virtual environment to develop your game then the module will not be installed to your main python path. Just do a pip install for the modules you are missing then try running pyinstaller again. Or run the pyinstaller in your virtual environment which might work but I have not tested.

Comment: I have not used a virtual enviroment for this project. I used Sublime Text to make it, which gets all the installed libraries from ```pip``` to itself. Also, as I said I've already tried installing the module once before I asked the quiestion and now. Still didn't work when I run it with the .exe app. The python file still runs the code perfectly though.

Comment: So it is letting you package it with no errors it is when you run the exe that you get the issue?

Comment: Exactly. When I open and run the python file, program works. When I run it from the .exec, it doesn't.